# Is this running malicious software from a System.Shell.execute?

Tags: jscript, windows-desktop-gadgets

I have downloaded a Window Gadget and found this function from the javascript.
What this function does? Is it malicious?

Before I run the Widget, I commented out first the function call and it seems this function is not necessary to run the widget.

```
function LaunchPowerApplet()
{
    System.Shell.execute(System.Environment.getEnvironmentVariable("SystemRoot") + "\\system32\\mblctr.exe");
}
```

Comment: are you sure this is javascript?

Comment: My educated guess is that it executes `mblctr.exe`.

Comment: Judging by the Execute, it executes something in the system root\system32 called mblctr.exe (Windows Mobility Center) - more info on mblctr can be found here: http://bit.ly/172q1hP

Comment: @VAGABOND: Yes it is Javascript, targeted for Windows Sidebar probably.

Comment: is it necessary to call that executable file?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms723232(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- [System.Shell.execute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms723232%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is a method from the [Windows Sidebar API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa965853%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that is used to launch an application.
- `%WINDIR%\system32\mblctr.exe` is the executable for the [Windows Mobility Center](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/products/features/windows-mobility-center), a tool that *«puts commonly used laptop settings in one spot so you can access them easily on the go»*.

Whether it's necessary or not is hard to say without knowing what the gadget needs to accomplish. The function is called `LaunchPowerApplet` and Windows Mobility Center allows to configure the battery usage settings. It makes sense if the gadget is a battery level meter, it doesn't if it's a solitaire.

---

BTW, a [gadget](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa965850%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is *«a collection of XML, HTML, Microsoft JScript, and Cascading Style Sheets (CSS) files»* so it's technically not JavaScript but JScript (Microsoft's ECMAScript implementation)

Answer (score 1):

Thia is just a windows mobility center exe it will help your gadget to run correctly. it will not harm your computer.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't say it was malicious since the application it is trying to launch is a standard windows component.

Why it wants to launch the [Mobility Center](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Mobility_Center) is a bit of a mystery, but without further context about what this widget is supposed to be able to do we can't comment.